# A specific website isn't working on my computer

Tags: networking, router, dns, proxy

A website, one website, is not loading on my computer [Windows 7]. It loads on other people's computers. I've tried several things -

```
> ipconfig /flushdns
> ping [name of website] -> no packets returned
> tracert [name of website] -> 1 * * * Request timed out (a bunch of times)
> arp -d * -> didn't really do anything
```

I've also switched the DNS servers I'm using to OpenDNS. Other websites load, but this one does not. If I use a proxy, I can access the website from my computer, but I'd like to fix the problem, because the website also has a linux server which I can't connect to either.

I used a local and online nslookup to confirm that the IP my computer is trying to access and the IP that the online nslookup found were the same. And yes, I did try accessing both https:// and http://

As far as I can tell, I don't have any viruses (and if I did it'd be unlikely for them to target this one website, and I tried disabling my firewall).

What else could I try? I'm on a university internet, so I don't think I can go fiddle with the router, but even if I could, several things I've tried suggest it's not the router.

Comment: When you ping it, does it resolve to the correct IP address?

Comment: You don't say which browser you are using. Do IE, Firefox & Chrome all give the same result?

Comment: @Paul It resolves to the same IP that an online nslookup resolves to.

Comment: @PeterFowler Yes, all three browsers give no result (although I thought testing it with ping would imply that).

Comment: Thought you may be pinging from within a website like speed test.net!

Comment: It turns out other people in my vicinity are having the same problem, so I'm guessing it's a problem with the university internet.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that it's something running in the background:

I once had an issue where one day, out of the blue, reddit wouldn't load on any browser I tried. I started Task Manager and killed any vaguely network-sounding processes that I figured probably weren't important, and after killing a program called Killer Network Manager, reddit suddenly worked again. I removed it and haven't had a problem with reddit or any other site since.

Answer (score 0):

See what the IP is that that site is resolving to on other peoples computers, and then add an entry for that site and IP to your hosts file. It's in /System32/drivers/etc/hosts on windows or /etc/hosts on linux. The format is

IP hostname

One per line, you can use tab or space between them.